# For Loop of a Linear Model Through a list in R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I am brand new to R, and have what is very likely an extremely simple and rudimentary problem involving figuring out how to do a For Loop with a set of data I have.

I have 10 csv files. Each file consists of a table with a set of data in columns and rows. I want to do a linear model function of one variable (i.e. one column) against another variable (i.e. another column) in each data set. My plan was to make a list of each of the csv files and then do a for loop through this list.

I have (1) assigned the csv files to a list:
    `hydro_list <- list(CA, CC, CF, CM, P1, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7)`

and (2) made a data frame that holds this list:
    `theDF <- data.frame(hydro_list)`

My code currently reads thus:

```
`for (i in 1:10)
{
  AVG_rising <- lm(dependent_variable~independent_variable, data=theDF)
  print(summary(AVG_rising))
}`
```

(Note: I derived the `1:10` because my list contains 10 items.)

This does print out the summary of the AVG, but it prints out 10 items of the same summary, as opposed to a different summary/results for each item within the csv list. It seems that it's not looping through/doing the function for each csv file.

How do I fix this? What am I missing? Moreover, how do I think through this differently so as to know what I am missing in future problems?

Thanks so much!

Comment: There are several problems in your code but the crux of the problem likely is the way you import the csv files. Could you detail that?

Comment: I imported the csv files like this:

`CA <- read.csv(file = "CA.csv", header = TRUE)`

Comment: The edit you provided suggesting the `[[i]]` did seem to fix the problem. What were the other problems in the code to which you were referring?

Comment: It is good as is, I'm sorry that was an overstatement assuming that you hadn't done the importation well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly imported the csvs in CA, CC etc. then you should work on hydro_list, using `i` to precise the data in hydro_list you want to use.

```
hydro_list <- list(CA, CC, CF, CM, P1, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7)

for (i in 1:10)
{
   AVG_rising <- lm(dependent_variable~independent_variable, data=hydro_list[[i]]) # note the [[i]]
   print(summary(AVG_rising))
}
```